# Synchronize value of column between two tables in different databases

Tags: mysql

I am new to `MYsql` and I have two independent systems that use `points(system1) and money(system2)`.
I need to make it so that column `money` from `bw_money` will equal the same as `pointshop_data`. So that if a change in value will happen in either column it will still be equal to the same amount int he other column. Also this needs to happen at a really fast pace as it is a live item that needs updating on the fly.

```
(first database) pointshop_data = uniqueud, points
(second database)bw_money=  UID, steamid, money
```

Make `money` and `points` equal to each other.

Comment: Are the databases on the same host or on different hosts?

Comment: They are on the same host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html) to update one column when another changes. Triggers are procedures inside MySQL that are automatically executed on some event, such as, changing the value of a column.

You'll need an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger for both of the tables to propagate change in both directions.

(Obviously having the value in two places is a requirement, so I'm skipping the lecture on [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization))

Comment: Could you help me make one i never done this(im using phpmyadmin)